# Solving for $x$ in a complicated equation with fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{\frac12+x}3 20=\frac{\frac12 - x}2 25$$

I need help solving for $x$.

Comment: Are the $[y]$ Gauss brackets (floor) or just to parenthesise?

Comment: I'm assuming the former...

Comment: I'm a 10th grader and have not a clue what that means, "floor"... I'm not not a plummer/mathemetician

Comment: I'm so sorry about that.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Since you are new to this site, I recommend you read the help pages for asking good questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and http://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. When asking a question, it is recommended that you: 1. Make the title specific and relevant to your question; 2. Demonstrate a "good faith" attempt at solving the problem; and 3. Tag questions responsibly.

Comment: Show your thoughts about this problem.

Comment: I forgot to change the title... This equation is neither long, nor weird, nor complex. It doesn't even take up a whole line! And in any case, that's a poor description of any problem.

Comment: As for the brackets, $[x]$ sometimes means the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. It can be confusing, so $(x)$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ should be used, depending on what is intended.

Answer (score 3):

You have

$$\frac{0.5+x}3\cdot20=\frac{0.5-x}2\cdot25\;.$$

Simplify it a step at a time. If you don’t like fractions, you can multiply through by $6$ to get rid of them: $6\cdot\frac{20}3=40$, and $6\cdot\frac{25}2=75$, so you get

$$40(0.5+x)=75(0.5-x)\;,$$

or, after multiplying out,

$$20+40x=\frac{75}2-75x\;.$$

And you can multiply through by $2$ to get rid of this last fraction:

$$40+80x=75-150x\;.$$

Can you finish it from there?

Comment: @David: Thanks. Apparently I omitted `\frac` twice.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this sort of answer really serves a didactic function. The school has failed this student terribly; how does this ameliorate the problem?

Comment: @dfeuer: It’s possible that the OP has all of the necessary tools and is simply confused by the superficial complexity of the equation as compared, say, with the last one in my answer; if so, walking the OP through the steps needed to reduce it to something more obviously manageable may help the OP over the hump not just in this problem but more generally. But that’s not my primary concern: my primary concern is to help the OP to answer this question with some understanding of what’s being done.

Comment: I can see how the first purpose makes sense; I'm not understanding the second. Perhaps we can chat later.

Comment: @amWhy: No problem: that was a typo, pure and simple.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's what I meant to suggest: typo. I **know** you know how to multiply!!

Answer (score 1):

We have: $$\frac{\frac12+x}3 20=\frac{\frac12 - x}2 25\tag{1}$$

Now, note that your equation $(1)$ can be expressed equivalently as $(2)$, the following equation:

$$ \frac{20}{3}\left(\frac 12 +x\right) =\frac{25}{2} \left(\frac 12 - x\right)\tag{2}$$

Multiplying both sides of $(2)$ by $3$ and by $2$ gives us:

$$ \frac{\color{red}{3} \cdot 2 \cdot 20}{\color{red}{3}}\left(\frac 12 +x\right) =\frac{3\cdot \color{blue}{2}\cdot 25}{\color{blue}{2}} \left(\frac 12 - x\right)\tag{3}$$

$$\iff  2 \cdot 20\left(\frac 12 +x\right) =3\cdot 25 \left(\frac 12 - x\right)\tag{3}$$

$$\iff 40\left(\frac 12 + x \right) = 75 \left(\frac 12 - x\right) \iff 20 + 40x = \dfrac {75}{2} - 75 x\tag{5}$$

Multiplying both sides of the equation by $2$ gives us:

$$2\cdot 20  + 2\cdot 40x = 2\cdot \dfrac {75}{2} - 2\cdot 75 x \iff 40 + 80x = 75 - 150 x\tag{6}$$

$$\iff 80x + 150 x = 75 - 40\quad \iff \quad 230 x = 35$$

We can divide both sides of the equation by $230$, and then reduce the resulting fraction (by dividing numerator and denominator by $5$). This gives us: $$x = \dfrac {35}{230} = \dfrac{7}{46}$$

Comment: OP seems to have disappeared. +1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your brackets are parenthesis, and your $*$ means multiplication:

$$\frac{20}{3}(.5+x) = \frac{25}{2}(.5-x) \\
.5+x = \frac{3\cdot 25}{2\cdot 20}(.5-x) \\
x+0.5 = \frac{75}{40}(.5-x) \\
x +0.5 = \frac{75}{80}-\frac{75}{40}x \\
\left(\frac{75}{40}+1\right)x = \frac{75}{80}-\frac12 \\
\left(\frac{75}{40}+\frac{40}{40}\right)x = \frac{75}{80}-\frac{20}{40}
$$

Compute the numbers and divide.

Comment: The plural of _parenthesis_ is _parentheses_.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Careless fast post.